# How Can I Install the open-mplane Repository on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, metadata, ubuntu-20.04, yocto-project

I would like to install the open-mplane repository and run the open-mplane server from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/lf-connectivity/open-mplane).

> (Contains software implementing portions of the Management Plane (M-Plane) according to O-RAN Alliance specifications)

However, I am unsure where to begin. The provided readme files are complex and lack sufficient information. The repository was published two months ago, and I haven't been able to find any guides or tutorials to follow. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance on how to proceed with the installation and setup process. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: did you manage to find anything?